# disabling (or fixing) ReadCube WebReader on Firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf

Mac OSX 10.11.2, Firefox 45.0.1

I'm trying to access articles through Wiley publishers website (onlinelibrary.wiley.com) and the PDF viewing function forces me to use ReadCube Webreader, which fails every time to load my article. I also cannot download the article. I have full permissions to view the article, but everything but the first page is blurred out. I just want to use Adobe PDF Reader like I used to, but I cannot figure out how to disable ReadCube. I have toggle this setting `https://www.readcube.com/epdf_settings`, cleared my cookies, turned off my addblocker, but nothing works! If I use Safari, which I really don't want to do, it works just brilliantly. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

My add-on HTTPS Everywhere was interfering. It can be disabled by clicking the HTTPS Everywhere Icon in the browser window, and selecting the red-highlighted processes that are being encrypted by clicking on it. This is a bad answer to my question, because I'm not entirely sure how this has fixed the problem, but it has worked.